# Hyperlink in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, hyperlink, interactive

Suppose, on the left hand side, I have about 10 symbols and on the right hand side, there is some text for details of the said symbol. After clicking a particular symbol, the corresponding text should appear in the same slide, i.e. on the right hand side. How can I do this in PowerPoint 2007?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably any number of insanely complex ways of doing this.  I'd do it the easy way ...

Create your first slide with the symbols on the left and some text on the right.

Duplicate the slide ten times.  Change each of the duplicates to include the necessary detail text.

Now go back to the first slide, make each symbol a link to the appropriate details slide.

Finally, select all the symbols, press Ctrl+C to copy them, then go to each of the detail slides, select and delete the symbols, then paste in the ones from the first slide.  The ones that have the links ... now you don't have to create the links on each of the details slides.